# Restricting shown products to those not deleted in Spree

Tags: spree

I'm using Spree 0.70.

In my home page view, I have the following to show a "featured" category:

```
<% @taxon = Taxon.find_by_permalink('featured', :include => :products) %>
<%= render :partial => 'shared/products', :locals => {:products => @taxon.products } %>
```

However, it's showing products that are deleted. How can I stop this?

I think `@variant.deleted_at = nil` may be what I need to use, but I'm not sure how to build that into the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using this query instead

```
@taxon.products.active
```

This will not only *not* show products that are deleted, but will also *not* show products that have an `available_on` date set to after today.

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear - the answer was terribly simple.

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/products', :locals => {:products => @taxon.products.where(:deleted_at => nil) } %>
```

(Still a noob with programming Ruby and Rails.)